# Not Rolling the log figleaf_inboundevent.log every two hours testing using HH in filePattern

Tags: java, log4j2

In the Log4J2 FileNamePattern that specifies Hours(HH) for the second logfile called figleaf- it is not creating a new file every two hours?  Also - I noticed that the logs/LOGFILE1.log is created, but it is not getting the year-month-day and hour extension it its naming.  The file is created without the extensions after the application is restarted.

Do you see anything wrong with the logfile properties preventing the figleaf log file from being created every two hours?

```
status = info

property.Default.Pattern = [%d{MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS}] %X{context} %X{tenant} %-5p [%t] [%c] %m%n
property.Default.Level = info
appender.LOGFILE1.type = RollingFile
appender.LOGFILE1.name = LOGFILE1
appender.LOGFILE1.fileName = logs/LOGFILE1.log
appender.LOGFILE1.filePattern = logs/LOGFILE1-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.%i
appender.LOGFILE1.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.LOGFILE1.layout.pattern = ${Default.Pattern}
appender.LOGFILE1.policies.type = Policies
# To rollover the log file LOGFILE1 daily testing
appender.LOGFILE1.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.LOGFILE1.policies.time.interval = 1
appender.LOGFILE1.policies.time.modulate = true
# To change log file after 50mb size
appender.LOGFILE1.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.LOGFILE1.policies.size.size = 50mb
appender.LOGFILE1.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.LOGFILE1.strategy.max = 31
rootLogger.level = info
rootLogger.appenderRefs = root
rootLogger.appenderRef.root.ref = LOGFILE1

#------ Configuration for Inbound Logging for figleaf ------
appender.figleaf_inboundevent.type = RollingFile
appender.figleaf_inboundevent.name = figleaf_inboundevent
appender.figleaf_inboundevent.fileName = logs/figleaf_inboundevent.log
# To rollover the log file every two hours testing using HH in filePattern
appender.figleaf_inboundevent.filePattern = logs/figleaf_inboundevent-%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH}.log.%i
appender.figleaf_inboundevent.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.figleaf_inboundevent.layout.pattern = ${Default.Pattern}
appender.figleaf_inboundevent.policies.type = Policies
# To rollover the log file every two hours testing
appender.figleaf_inboundevent.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.figleaf_inboundevent.policies.time.interval = 2
appender.figleaf_inboundevent.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.figleaf_inboundevent.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.figleaf_inboundevent.policies.size.size = 50mb
appender.figleaf_inboundevent.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.figleaf_inboundevent.strategy.max = 31

logger.figleaf_inbound_InboundSchedulable.name = com.lawson.ma.sdi.figleaf.adapter.InboundSchedulable
logger.figleaf_inbound_InboundSchedulable.level = INFO

logger.figleaf_inbound_InboundSchedulable.additivity = false
logger.figleaf_inbound_InboundSchedulable.appenderRef.figleaf_inboundevent.ref = figleaf_inboundevent

logger.figleaf_inbound_ProcessInbound.name = com.lawson.ma.sdi.figleaf.inbound.ProcessInbound
logger.figleaf_inbound_ProcessInbound.level = INFO
logger.figleaf_inbound_ProcessInbound.additivity = false
logger.figleaf_inbound_ProcessInbound.appenderRef.figleaf_inboundevent.ref = figleaf_inboundevent

logger.figleaf_inbound_ProcessADT.name = com.lawson.ma.sdi.figleaf.inbound.ProcessADT
logger.figleaf_inbound_ProcessADT.level = INFO
logger.figleaf_inbound_ProcessADT.additivity = false
logger.figleaf_inbound_ProcessADT.appenderRef.figleaf_inboundevent.ref = figleaf_inboundevent

logger.figleaf_inbound_ProcessSIU.name = com.lawson.ma.sdi.figleaf.inbound.ProcessSIU
logger.figleaf_inbound_ProcessSIU.level = INFO
logger.figleaf_inbound_ProcessSIU.additivity = false
logger.figleaf_inbound_ProcessSIU.appenderRef.figleaf_inboundevent.ref = figleaf_inboundevent

logger.figleaf_inbound_ProcessCSU.name = com.lawson.ma.sdi.figleaf.inbound.ProcessCSU
logger.figleaf_inbound_ProcessCSU.level = INFO
logger.figleaf_inbound_ProcessCSU.additivity = false
logger.figleaf_inbound_ProcessCSU.appenderRef.figleaf_inboundevent.ref = figleaf_inboundevent

logger.figleaf_inbound_InboundManager.name = com.lawson.ma.sdi.figleaf.inbound.data.InboundManager
logger.figleaf_inbound_InboundManager.level = INFO
logger.figleaf_inbound_InboundManager.additivity = false
logger.figleaf_inbound_InboundManager.appenderRef.figleaf_inboundevent.ref = figleaf_inboundevent

logger.figleaf_inbound_InboundManagerImpl.name = com.lawson.ma.sdi.figleaf.inbound.data.InboundManagerImpl
logger.figleaf_inbound_InboundManagerImpl.level = INFO
logger.figleaf_inbound_InboundManagerImpl.additivity = false
logger.figleaf_inbound_InboundManagerImpl.appenderRef.figleaf_inboundevent.ref = figleaf_inboundevent

logger.figleaf_inbound_ADTManager.name = com.lawson.ma.sdi.figleaf.inbound.data.ADTManager
logger.figleaf_inbound_ADTManager.level = INFO
logger.figleaf_inbound_ADTManager.additivity = false
logger.figleaf_inbound_ADTManager.appenderRef.figleaf_inboundevent.ref = figleaf_inboundevent

logger.figleaf_inbound_ADTManagerImpl.name = com.lawson.ma.sdi.figleaf.inbound.data.ADTManagerImpl
logger.figleaf_inbound_ADTManagerImpl.level = INFO
logger.figleaf_inbound_ADTManagerImpl.additivity = false
logger.figleaf_inbound_ADTManagerImpl.appenderRef.figleaf_inboundevent.ref = figleaf_inboundevent

logger.figleaf_inbound_CSUManager.name = com.lawson.ma.sdi.figleaf.inbound.data.CSUManager
logger.figleaf_inbound_CSUManager.level = INFO
logger.figleaf_inbound_CSUManager.additivity = false
logger.figleaf_inbound_CSUManager.appenderRef.figleaf_inboundevent.ref = figleaf_inboundevent

logger.figleaf_inbound_CSUManagerImpl.name = com.lawson.ma.sdi.figleaf.inbound.data.CSUManagerImpl
logger.figleaf_inbound_CSUManagerImpl.level = INFO
logger.figleaf_inbound_CSUManagerImpl.additivity = false
logger.figleaf_inbound_CSUManagerImpl.appenderRef.figleaf_inboundevent.ref = figleaf_inboundevent

logger.figleaf_inbound_SIUManager.name = com.lawson.ma.sdi.figleaf.inbound.data.SIUManager
logger.figleaf_inbound_SIUManager.level = INFO
logger.figleaf_inbound_SIUManager.additivity = false
logger.figleaf_inbound_SIUManager.appenderRef.figleaf_inboundevent.ref = figleaf_inboundevent

logger.figleaf_inbound_SIUManagerImpl.name = com.lawson.ma.sdi.figleaf.inbound.data.SIUManagerImpl
logger.figleaf_inbound_SIUManagerImpl.level = INFO
logger.figleaf_inbound_SIUManagerImpl.additivity = false
logger.figleaf_inbound_SIUManagerImpl.appenderRef.figleaf_inboundevent.ref = figleaf_inboundevent

logger.figleaf_inbound_InboundException.name = com.lawson.ma.sdi.figleaf.exception.InboundException
logger.figleaf_inbound_InboundException.level = INFO
logger.figleaf_inbound_InboundException.additivity = false
logger.figleaf_inbound_InboundException.appenderRef.figleaf_inboundevent.ref = figleaf_inboundevent
```

Comment: If it does not rotate every two hours, how often does it rotate? What version for Log4j2 Core are you using?

Comment: It's not rotating at all - I've installed log4j-jcl-2.17.1.  Does the figleaf logger to complex with multiple packages?   open to suggestions on how to troubleshoot by process of eliminating complexity if that's an issue.

Comment: also - is the rootLogger.appenderRef.root config correct ?